# Add a blog to a node.js app

Tags: node.js, heroku, blogs

I have a SAAS app that is running on node.js and Express.

I need to add a blog to make some blog content and share it on

```
http://www.myapp.com/blog/
```

Is there something ready to use that i can add to my app something like WordPress?

Comment: I doubt there's anything as extensive as wordpress in node.js, but there's certainly tutorials out there with several libraries that outline how to model articles in a database, all you'd have to do then is display them.

Comment: @hedi so what did you decide, were you able to run blog on your site like this: mywebsite.com/blog ? How did you do it?

Answer (score 2):

> Note: I'll answer you while it's still open and just sitting here, but I'm voting to close as "primarily opinion based".

I really like [Ghost](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost). Keep in mind I'm only pimping my own blog because it's relevant. I use Ghost for my blog at [codetunnel.io](http://codetunnel.io) if you want to see a working example. It's completely written in node and is much lighter-weight than WordPress. In classic node style it does one thing and does it well. I like the simplicity.

I'm sure there are other options out there but if you want a very simple but robust blogging platform written in node, Ghost is the one IMO. You can download a [ready to publish](https://ghost.org/download/) copy of it as well if you don't want to build the source.

Comment: Is it possible to do the same thing written in the other answer with ghost?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use wintersmith to do this.  You can even keep your blog in a /blog/ URL.  It usually builds my site in a few seconds, and is familiar to use if you are already using the MEAN stack.  It took me a week to try a few blog engines and figure it all out, but you can do the steps below and also browse the wintersmith documentation in a couple hours.

1. Install wintersmith
   `$ npm install wintersmith -g`
2. Make a directory in your app containing the wintersmith framework
   `$ wintersmith new app_blog`
3. In the wintersmith config.json file, set the base url to “/blog/”
   `"baseUrl": "/blog/"`
4. Add the wintersmith build folder to your express application app.js file so your site can see all of those static pages.
   `app.use('/blog/',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'app_blog/build')));`
5. Modify the template index.jade file to point to the correct page for the archive.  Remove the leading '/' from  `href='/archive.html'`
6. In the app_blog directory to generate the static blog pages, run
   `$ wintersmith build`
7. modify the wintersmith layout.jade template to integrate any headers or footers you want.